# Very slow leak below shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing

If you look at picture below, the cold water line is on the right. I am having a very slow leak beneath the metal nut at the bottom and the metal threads that come out from cold water supply. It does not drip, it is a very slow leak that could be described as oozing very very slowly. I have attempted to tighten and it won’t budge. I really don’t want to take it off unless absolutely necessary. Are there any suggestions or any products, I could use to stop this leak? I had thought of using pipe sealant, but I don’t know if that is an option here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post a close-up picture of the water line, where it comes out of the floor (by your description, that is where the leak is, no?). We need to see those fittings better to be able to help you.

Comment: I added 2 additional close-up pictures. The blue arrow is where I think leak is at based on buildup there and feeling water from that spot.

Answer (score 1):

I put some pipe sealent on the area pointed in picture plus the area where icemaker and cold water shutoff valves are. No leaks yet.

Comment: How is this solution holding up? and what was the brand of pipe sealant you used?

Comment: I believe it was Rectotseal T plus 2. It was brand sold at Lowe’s . Working great. No leaks. Doesn’t look as good as Teflon tape, but does the job. I could never get Teflon tape sealed area to quit leaking. Hope this helps.